# Using r2DBC MSSQL library, if you run native query with 'IN' clause, cause exception

Tags: spring-webflux, r2dbc

how to run a native query with In clause using r2dbc-MSSQL in spring-webflux application.

I tried with following code.

```
List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList("smith" , "jones");
Flux.from(connection.
        createStatement("SELECT DISTINCT firstName FROM dbo.PersonDetails "  +
                "WHERE lastName IN (@nameList)")
        .bind("nameList", nameList)
        .execute())
        .flatMap(result -> result.map(
                        (row, rowMetadata) -> row.get("FirstName" , String.class)))
        .collectList().subscribe(this::PrintResults);
```

the following exception thrown:
2020-12-02 23:54:48.772 ERROR 15571 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode [[smith, jones]] parameter of type [java.util.Arrays$ArrayList]